# facebook iframe apps youtube embed error unsafe javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube, youtube-api

i use this embed code in my facebook iframe apps :

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but i got this error on firebug console :

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx/?state=f1f21e5736ae4e193f7234cae34842be&code=AQDKwOTwhCcU0DiWBuVO5igIudWEtypxt4xMNjDTN_dtK5ltdFb7e-2-EW1rWeIotL3v1RaanI390wWwkCLJH1dpFr76rCOZyKGCVCgBC40tUIaseY3FxLoXsoqLIRZ3X6zW3HgXr-YIY0dOSpPBKugxVKOT_28W-ejhQoFkbFg0iuTg-tonVJeCrRyXKg4yc9U#_=_ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

i have place facebook meta tag on my html header :

```
<meta property="og:video" content="<?php echo $youtube_url;?>" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="<?php echo $youtube_url;?>" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

but i keep getting those error.

any clue/advice on how to embed youtube video in a facebook iframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your are using `https` in your Youtube URL .

Answer (score 0):

Despite being irritating to see in the console logs, this error can be safely ignored.

This is caused by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The YouTube `iframe` is attempting to communicate or access something in the parent website via JavaScript, and is denied access by your browser because it does not reside on the same domain, and thus, can't be trusted.